# React Component Not "Reacting" to TailwindCSS Class Name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, tailwind-css

I'm currently attempting to create a simple React app that tracks and displays the (rough) position of the ISS (International Space Station) on a flat map using data retrieved from Open Notify's ISS API. I am fairly new to developing so I'm not very familiar with what I'm working with but it seems to me that almost everything is working except for one final step. The issue is that my React component is ignoring the absolute positioning defined in its class name.

I have a parent component Map.jsx that uses axios to get data from the API and renders the child component ISS.jsx using this data (passed through prop). Then ISS.jsx takes this data and "calculates" the correct class name (cName) for the image that it renders (where image is a red point signifying the ISS's location). Basically it does some math to determine pixel quantities for the image's absolute positioning. I am 99.999% certain that this process is being done correctly, because running console.log(cName) right before the final return statement yields the correct class name every time (when I manually paste this resulting class name into my code I get the correct positioning of the red point). But when I pass the variable cName (which is a string with the correct class name as its value) instead, the red point just centres itself at the top of the map and doesn't budge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for two whole days. Additionally, if there are any other issues (e.g. something wrong with my axios setup or my hooks, etc.) please let me know as well since once again I'm pretty new to all this.

Thank you so much.

Map.jsx:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ISS from "./ISS";
import axios from "axios";

function Map() {
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {   
        setInterval(() => {
            getCoordinates();
        }, 4000)
    }, [])

    const getCoordinates =  async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
            setCoordinates(res.data);
            setLoading(false)
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    return(
        <div className="relative w-[620px] h-[475px] map flex content-center justify-center">
            {!loading && <ISS coordinates={coordinates} />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

ISS.jsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import pixel from "./pixel.jpeg";

function ISS(props) {
    const latitude = parseFloat(props.coordinates.latitude);
    const longitude = parseFloat(props.coordinates.longitude);
    var lat;
    var lon;
    // origin: lat = 315, lon = 280
    // top: 60px
    // bottom: 500px
    // left: 0px
    // right: 600px
    if(latitude > 0)
        lat = Math.floor(315-2.8333*latitude);
    else
        lat = Math.floor(315-2.0556*latitude);

    if(longitude > 0)
        lon = Math.floor(280+1.7778*longitude);
    else
        lon = Math.floor(280+1.5556*longitude);
    
    console.log("latitude: " + latitude + "\nlongitude: " + longitude)
    return(<img src={pixel} alt="ISS" className="z-1 absolute size-3" style={{top: `${lat}px`, left: `${lon}px`}} />)
}

export default ISS;
```

Here is a photo of the [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU348.png).
Notice the position of the red point; that's where it always defaults to no matter what "cName" is calculated to be.

Comment: Will you also add your `ISS.jsx` code to your question? Stack overflow asks that we [don't use photos of code in our question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), rather code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS.

[Dynamic class names in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

I would suggest storing the latitude and longitude values in variables and then applying them via the `style` prop:

```
<img
  src={pixel}
  alt='ISS'
  style={{top: `${lat}px`, left: `${lon}px`}}
  ...
/>
```

Cool project!

Comment: @PhilipChen Awesome! Be sure to [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)